# size or length of a Document object

Tags: java, android

How can i get the size of an Document object?

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputStream iStr = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        doc = db.parse(iStr);

        ???? --> Log.i("Bytes",String.valueOf(doc.get????));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement this would be to write a custom subclass of [FilterInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) that counts the bytes that are read from the stream.  (The class would be analogous to [LineNumberInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberInputStream.html) ...)

Then wrap the URL stream with your filter:

```
InputStream iStr = new ByteNumberInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Finally when you are done reading/parsing the stream, call some method on your filter object to fetch the byte count.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the document to string using asXml() and using String.length()?

Comment: asXml() is not available in android sdk, uses : org.w3c.dom.Document